# Problem to insert new user to DB after checking if email exist sqlite

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm trying to prevent double insertion of users to DB and when i check email every time I get the message:

```
my email already exists
```

Thanks for answering.

Check if `userEmail` already exists: `DataBaseHelper` class:

```
public boolean checkIfExists(String userEmail){
    db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    String query = "select "+ COL_EMAIL + " from " +TABLE_NAME;
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    String existEmail;

   if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            existEmail = cursor.getString(0);

            if (existEmail.equals(userEmail)) {
                return true;
            }
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    return false;
}
```

Validate Email, check if email already exists: `Registration` class:

```
private boolean validateEmail() {
    String emailInput = textInputEmail.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();

    if (myDb.checkIfExists(emailInput)) {
        textInputEmail.setError("Email already exist");
        return false;
    } else if (emailInput.isEmpty()) {
        textInputEmail.setError("Field can't be empty");
        return false;
    } else if (!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(emailInput).matches()) {
        textInputEmail.setError("Please enter a valid email address");
        return false;
    } else {
        textInputEmail.setError(null);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the e-mail you are entering is not in the database? What happens on debugging?

Comment: This approach probably is not fail-safe, because in the you are checking the email in your Java code, another insert could have happened.  You would need to insert in a single transaction, or something along those lines.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be fine, but you should not be doing this as there could be another insert happening while you are iterating over all your `email` list. It's better to create the `email` field with `UNIQUE` constraint enabled and then do a direct insert to the DB to create the email. This will result in an exception in case the `email` already exists, which you can catch and handle appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should debug you code using Android Studio Debugger. It's very powerfull tool and I think it will help you to solve this issue.
If you are not able to use debugger you can insert System.out.println in intrested rows.

May be I would do it so (but using debugger is much better):

```
public boolean checkIfExists(String userEmail){

    System.out.println("INPUT: " + userEmail);
    db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    String query = "select "+ COL_EMAIL + " from " +TABLE_NAME;
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    String existEmail;

   if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {

            existEmail = cursor.getString(0);
            System.out.println("Checking email " + existEmail);
            if (existEmail.equals(userEmail)) {
                return true;
            }
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    return false;
}

private boolean validateEmail() {
    String emailInput = textInputEmail.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();
    System.out.println("Email is " + emailInput);

    if (myDb.checkIfExists(emailInput)) {
        textInputEmail.setError("Email already exist");
        return false;
    } else if (emailInput.isEmpty()) {
        textInputEmail.setError("Field can't be empty");
        return false;
    } else if (!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(emailInput).matches()) {
        textInputEmail.setError("Please enter a valid email address");
        return false;
    } else {
        textInputEmail.setError(null);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Also I want to pay your attention to next moments (you can simply skip it because it's only my thoughts):
1) In `checkIfExists` method you select ALL stored emails every time when you need to validate just once. I think it could be better if you will write sql-query for select only concrete email using `WHERE` expression.
2) In your `validateEmail` method you checking `emailInput.isEmpty()` and `!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(emailInput).matches()` **AFTER** you check email in DB. But it should be checked first of all because if email is empty or not valid from format point of view we can not check it in DB because is's probably not email:))